# alert dialog pops up even when different route is called

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a simple flutter app with two screens. On the first screen, i have an alert dialog that pops up every time a user visits the screen.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';


void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// The route configuration.
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const HomeScreen();
      },
      routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
          path: 'details',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const DetailsScreen();
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

/// The main app.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [MyApp]
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routeInformationProvider: _router.routeInformationProvider,
      routeInformationParser: _router.routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: _router.routerDelegate);
  }
}

/// The home screen
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Constructs a [HomeScreen]
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer(const Duration(seconds : 1), (() {
      showDialog(
        context: context, 
        builder: (context) {
          return someDialogy();
          
        });
        print('i have been called forth');
    }));
  
    super.initState();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.go('/details'),
              child: const Text('Go to the Details screen'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// The details screen
class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [DetailsScreen]
  const DetailsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Details Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <ElevatedButton>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.go('/'),
              child: const Text('Go back to the Home screen'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget someDialogy () {
  return AlertDialog(
    content: Center(
      child: Text('data'),
    ),

  );
}
```

When i try to navigate to my second screen using a hyperlink on web say http://localhost/secondscreen, the popup from my first screen shows up.
My guess is that in constructing the route stack, flutter calls the initstate in my first page which does show my popup. What is the best way to go around this while maintaining the popup that shows when my first page is called?

Answer (score 0):

it would be helpful to show some mode code on this, like the somedialogy() method

anyways I suspect the issue might be with your routing solution,
try

```
onPressed: () {
        // Navigate to the second route when the button is pressed
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
        );
      },
```

Comment: I am using navigator 2.0, but when i call the second screen using somehow flutter calls the initstate of the first screen alongside with it.  It seem like it calls first screen the second screen stack-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I think its all about **Timer**
try this:

```
 Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
 showDialog(
    context: context, 
    builder: (context) {
      return someDialogy();
    });});
```

read this for more about **Timer** [Understanding Flutter’s Timer class and Timer.periodic](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-flutter-timer-class-timer-periodic/)

and this [2 Types of Flutter Delay Widgets](https://www.flutterbeads.com/flutter-delay-widgets/)